# Is it possible to get personalization strings when pulling content from DE with Server-side JavaScript in emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, email, dataextensions, ssjs

I'm trying to use server-side JS to dynamically write variables based on the column headers of a data extension for an email. Then fill those variables with the row contents of those field headers.

I was able to do so with the below sample code I found.
The only problem is that any personalization strings in that content gets written out as that string name (`%%personalization_string%%`).
I know with AMPScript to use `TreatAsContent()`. 
Is it possible to do this with SSJS?
Thanks!

```
<script runat="server">

    Platform.Load("Core","1");
    var hidden_fields = "_CustomObjectKey,lookUpField";
    var DE = DataExtension.Init("DEContent");
    var data = DE.Rows.Lookup(["lookUpField"], [lookupValue]);

    if (data.length > 0) {
            Write("<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='3' style='border-collapse:collapse;'>");
            Write("<tr>");
            for (var key in data[0]) {
                    if (hidden_fields.indexOf(key) == -1) {
                                    Write("<th>" + key.replace("_"," ") + "</th>");
                    }
            }
            Write("</tr>");
            for (var i=0;i<= data.length;i++) {
                    var d = data[i];
                    Write("<tr>");
                    for (var key in d) {
                                    if (hidden_fields.indexOf(key) == -1) {
                                                    Write("<td>" + d[key] + "</td>");
                                    }
                    }
                    Write("</tr>");
            }
            Write("</table>");

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [this SFMC help page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_recipientGetValue.htm) outlines how to do it.  You can use the `Attribute.GetValue()` function like this:

```
var pString = Attribute.GetValue("personalization_string");
```